# Missed triggers in two-headed giant

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-two-headed-giant, mtg-regular-rel

My partner and I recently played in a Two-Headed Giant Sealed. As is the case with most multiplayer tournaments, the event was run at Regular REL. My partner has an upkeep trigger ([Thopter Spy Network](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thopter%20Spy%20Network)). The following events occur sequentially:

- Our opponent's pass the turn.
- I untap, draw a card, and mix it into my hand.
- My partner says, "Wait! I have an upkeep trigger."

Has the trigger been missed?

> 805.2. Within each team, the player seated in the rightmost seat from that team’s perspective is the primary player. If the players on a team can’t agree on a choice, such as which creatures attack or what order triggered abilities are put on the stack, the primary player makes that choice.

Comprehensive rule 805.2 states that if players on a team can't agree on a choice, the primary player decides. However, we didn't really disagree on anything, so I don't think 805.2 applies. I reference this rule because I have moved to the draw step, while my partner wants to remain in the upkeep step. I guess one could argue that I silently disagreed with him by drawing a card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the primary player has moved forward to the draw step, then the trigger was missed. If the secondary player is the one that drew a card, then that player has drawn extra cards.

In either case, at regular REL, you should call a judge, explain what happened, and allow the judge to decide whether the trigger was missed or whether the game should be rolled back. If the game is rolled back, you would have to put a random card from your hand on top of your library, then do your upkeep stuff, and then continue as normal with a reminder to play more carefully. From [Judging at Regular](https://www.wizards.com/ContentResources/Wizards/WPN/Main/Documents/Magic_The_Gathering_Judging_at_Regular_REL_PDF1.pdf):

> If the identity of the card(s) were known to all players, return them to their proper location. Otherwise, determine how many extra cards have been drawn, take that many cards at random from the player’s hand and place them on top of the library. Don't shuffle the library after doing this!

In general, play penalties at regular REL are basically nonexistent, and mistakes should be fixed more often than punished.

Comment: You seem to be describing the *remedy* for a missed trigger. Just to be clear, are you saying that the trigger was in fact missed?

Comment: If the primary player has moved forward a phase, then yes the trigger was missed. If the other player had moved forward, it would have been a drawing extra cards (but still probably has the same remedy).

Comment: If that's your answer to the question, you should write it as your answer.

Comment: I think you had my partner and I mixed up in your answer. I'm the one that drew a card. I went ahead and edited the answer for you, and while I was at it, I absorbed your previous comment into the answer. I have to ask: did you make up the "put a random card on top" fix, or did that come from somewhere?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out and edited your answer again.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter given the REL, but I'm still wondering about the missed trigger part. The rules try to avoid this kind of thing with normal games: "Players may not cause triggered abilities controlled by an opponent to be missed by taking game actions or otherwise prematurely advancing the game. For example, if a player draws a card during his or her draw step [...]" Given that 2HG rules are notoriously weird, it's not a stretch to think that judges could reasonably apply the same rules here, even though it's a teammate not an opponent.